# Changing ActionBar and SearchView backgrounds

Tags: android, android-theme, android-actionbar, android-searchmanager

I was trying to use the Holo Light theme with dark action bars as recommended on [android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html).

This is my themes.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/dark_header</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The result without using the search interface is the expected, but when I use the `SearchView` the background is from Holo.Light theme:

[image: Correct result] [image: Incorrect background]

There is any way to change the SearchView default style on the ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be your answer:

[How do I keep ActionBar items' background the same...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146078/how-do-i-keep-actionbar-items-background-the-same-while-changing-the-apps-main)

In a nutshell:

> Try replacing
>
> `<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/dark_header</item>` with
>
> `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/dark_header</item>`

Answer (score 0):

[This link is most useful to create theme of actionbar in android.](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) May this one is useful to you also..

You have to just create and save xml files and put in respective folder.

Thank you.